# How to detect Portrait photos?

Tags: android, photo, portrait

I have a gallery app and I need a reliable way of detecting Portrait photos with reasonable performance. Currently I just loop through everything in a folder and check if it is a folder starting with "IMG_", but it is a rather slow solution, not to talk about how ugly it is. Is there any better solution? I found no flag for it, or anything whatsoever in the MediaStore.

By portrait I don't mean the images' orientation, but that new Portrait camera functionality with for example creating a selfie, while the background is blurred.

Comment: How do you determine that a picture is 'a Portrait'?

Answer (score 0):

There's no good and simple solution to detect if this Image is Portrait foto

All you can do is a  query all Images via ContentResolver with [URI from this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html)
then check all images with portrait orientation using this [column](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html#ORIENTATION) and then use some algorythms to check if there is face on this photo

Comment: I dont mean portrait as the orientation, but the new Portrait feature. I wrote it there.